# Error creating Transaction with pyethereum: Can only serialize integers

Tags: transactions, cold-storage, python, pyethereum

I'm following the instructions [found here](http://vitalik.ca/files/python_cold_wallet_instructions.txt) to create an offline Transaction. When executing, the following line, I get "Can only serialize integers" exception raised by rlp. I did import pdb;pdb.pm() and the address is a string, not an integer (obviously). Any idea what's going on?

```
t = ethereum.transactions.Transaction(nonce, 60 * 10**9, 21000, to, value, '').sign(k)
```

Comment: I have tried that and it works for me. What version of ethereum package do you have? Can you show the values behind variables `nonce`, `to`, `value`, `k`?

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace (error) that is output?

Comment: The script link to the txt file is down.